SQL Query - How to combine 2 count statements in to single query
I have 2 queries which give count of cases based upon a condition
Query 1:
Select count(unique c.caseid) as New_cases from caseinfo c where 
(c.crtdate between TO_DATE('2024/07/08') AND TO_DATE('2024/07/11')) and c.channel is not null;

Query 2:
Select count(unique c.caseid) as Old_cases from caseinfo c where 
(c.crtdate between TO_DATE('2024/07/08') AND TO_DATE('2024/07/11')) and c.channel is null;

Both the queries have just a difference of null condition at the end.How can we combine these 2 in to a single query.
Any help would be appreciated.

I'd try using a case statement with your c.channel to determine whether to count a case as new or old.

this doesn't look like mysql.  please tag with your actual database system

Select (sum( case when c.channel is null then 1 else 0 end)) as new_cases,
Sum ( case when c.channel is not null then 1 else 0 end)) as old_ cases…..
